# nServiceBus deployment approach on a single machine

Tags: nservicebus

I'm looking to put nServiceBus onto a single machine and am wondering if my understanding of a simple deployment is correct.

I intend to deploy each logical publisher and subscriber in their own service (as per advice [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nservicebus/index.php?title=Generic_Host)), and for each to have their own message queue (I will be using MSMQ).  To deploy another subscriber is then as simple as adding the service and the queue.  To remove it you just remove the service and the queue.

Is it really as simple as that for a low message volume single machine deployment?

Are there any serious gotchas I need  be aware of with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really should be it.  The other thing you may want to consider is at least putting your error queue(s) on another machine in case that single machine crashes.  This way you can still get an idea as to what the errors where.  I think in a production environment you may want to consider a cluster to make it a little bit more reliable.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it's good to get some clarification - it just seemed "too easy"!  As for using a cluster, am I right is thinking I have to use DB storage for this?

Comment: DB storage is your best bet for subscription storage.  You can cluster that as well.  The cluster for the machine will ensure that if one of the nodes goes down, your processing continues to live.